# rsync: deleted files reappear/transferred files disappear after some period of time

Tags: linux, file, rsync

I'm having this very awkward problem while using rsync between two linux machines. I have a workstation at home that does most of my computations and another machine at work that I transfer files between. For quite a while I've had no problems transferring files between the two machines. I run the transfer command, given below, and the files copied over with no problems.

```
rsync -avz --delete-after --rsh='ssh -p 22' -u --progress $homecomp:$HOME/folder $HOME/.
```

Recently, I've started having problems where after a few days the files that get deleted with the above command, and those that get transferred, seem to get lost in the work machine. In other words, files that are deleted reappear on the work machine and files that were transferred must be transferred again. After a rsync run I usually check to make sure things work correctly and the files always get deleted or transferred. So I have no idea how in the heck the files can just disappear or magically return. These files are always what was last transferred by the command.

This really only started happening after I added some symbolic links from the above folder and another rsynced folder to my Documents folder, which I sync between the two systems. The problem definitely does not happen every time, but it happens a lot. I use the same above command for the Document syncing as well. The files that disappear or reappear are not only those that are sym linked.

So basically, I rsync files, they get transferred or deleted. A day or so later, the transferred files disappear and the deleted files reappear. Repeat.

I'm not sure what other information I can provide without going overboard, so hopefully this is enough to provide some ideas of the problem. This isn't a horrible problem, as I can just rsync content again when the files disappear. However, it does eat up my data limits with my cable provider, which is kind of annoying because they throttle when you exceed 400GB a month. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but I had issues with --delete-after before.
Most of the times I'm simply using --delete, like this:

rsync -az --delete -e ssh /home/foo/bar/ foobar@10.0.0.1:/home/bar/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I performed my normal routine right before posting this question and just now had to rerun it again since the files reappeared and such. I tried doing it with --delete instead of --delete-after this time though. Hopefully this helps, but I'll let you know if it does help at all.

Comment: Sadly, this did not help at all. The problem still exists regardless of the delete method used. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

Have encountered a similar issue and found this question while looking for answers.

My problem was rsyncing files from server A to server B, where files on server B reverted back to their old versions 15 minutes past every hour.

It was so regular that I thought it had to be a script, but I could not find anything on these servers. Created a workaround: a cron job to rsync the files from server A just after they revert back to their old versions on server B. Further investigation showed that there was a script running on a completely different server that I did not take into account at all (assumed it could not be the case) that was the cause of that change.

It is not possible for the rsynced files just to change back to their previous version or disappear or appear again after deletion. If this is what's happening, there must be an agent somewhere that is causing that action.

For anyone in that situation I would recommend first to identify when exactly this change occurs, then start looking for a cause in all possible places (do NOT assume anything, check even the most obvious and unexpected things).